# (Objective C) NSDate is nil to convert a date in String

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I have this string date:

> Wed, 14 Oct 2015 9:58 am CDT

And I'm try to convert this String to NSData with this code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EE, d LLL YYYY HH:mm a Z"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"Wed, 14 Oct 2015 9:58 am CDT"];
```

But date, which is a `NSDate` variable is always `nil`. I have tried to change my `DateFormat` with different syntax but I have the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is you are using [capital `Z` instead of lowercase `z`](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for the time zone abbreviation. I also suggest reducing `EEE` to one `E`, changing `LLL` to `MMM`, using `yyyy` for year and `h` instead of `HH` for the hour.

```
"E, d MMM yyyy h:mm a z"
```

As a quick hint to date formatting issues, try converting a date to a string first and comparing the output.

Comment: Also `hh` instead of `HH` and I think he also has to set locale considering his date format contains English patterns.

Comment: The last sentence of your answer should just be the canonical answer to any `NSDateFormatter` question.

Comment: Based on your last sentence, the format should be "`EEE, d MMM yyyy h:mm a z"` though `E` will also work in addition to `EEE`. Note the use of `h` instead of `hh` since the example isn't `09` for the hour.

Comment: All updated, thanks for pointing out the inconsistencies, example added after suggestions.